# Unwanted edit link on front page

Tags: themes

I'm learning but not fast enough.  I have an EDIT link under the title on the first page of my site.  I'm using localhost.  Changing the theme seems to eliminate it.  It occurs with Twenty Seventeen.

{Twenty Seventeen image}

What is a Motorhome?

EDIT --- This is a link to the edit page.  It sure isn't wanted on a published page.

Comment: It only appears when you're logged in, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 3):

It's common for themes to add an `Edit` link on every post, if you are logged in and have the privilege to edit the post.

It's added via [`get_edit_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_edit_post_link) function, which appears only when you are logged in.

There's nothing to worry about, it's actually a good feature.